# Get result from two numbers

Tags: math, indexing

Simple and quick question, is there any formula to know the result between two values?

For example, if I know that position 1 is equal to 100pixels and position 600 is equal to 1000pixels, how could I know how many pixels is position 300?

Thanks

Comment: You mean like linear interpolation?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams not sure what you mean, but I think so

Answer (score 0):

If the relation between a position and pixels is linear than the formula is:

```
px(p) = (p2 - p1) / (px2 - px1) * p + px1
```

where `p1` and `p2` are the two positions and `px1` and `px2` are the two pixel values and `p` is the position you want the pixel value for.

It is called *linear interpolation*. If you draw the situation with position on the x-axis and pixels on the y-axis and put a little bit of math into it you can surely derive it yourself.

Comment: You should also mention that this is called "linear interpolation", which would make it easier to google for related information.

Comment: Mhh thank you for your answer, but it looks like it isn't working, I did **local ofst = starty + (mapcount - 1) / (endy - starty) * inf.scrollpos + starty** but is giving me a wrong postions.
EDIT:
Going to Google what Lasse said, ty